# Asterisk Realtime Configuration using VIEW

Tags: postgresql, configuration, asterisk

I work with asterisk 11.2.1 and use realtime configuration(database PostgreSQL).
There is a configuration for table

```
file.conf => driver,database[,table[,priority]]
```

but I want to use **view** instead **table**. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From SQL `SELECT` point of view, `VIEW` is rather difficult to tell apart from `TABLE`. Because of this, you should be able to use view name in place of table name, as long as your config source is used only for reading.

However, if your table will be used by Asterisk for writing - like inserting rows into CDR table, then views will NOT work out of the box. Limited support for updateable views is planned for PostgreSQL 9.3 (it only works if view is based on single table). Alternatively, you can create `INSTEAD OF` trigger on a view which will update appropriate originating tables. Considering this complexity, it is far easier to avoid using views with Asterisk.